# MapInfo Pro 16, getting polylines in my polygon, after enclosing

Tags: polygon, mapinfo, line

I'm a novice user of MapInfo (using for a couple of months). Recently I have been encountering a problem when converting polylines to polygons. After digitizing an area using polylines, I use the enclose (polylines to regions) option to create my polygons, (one table with individual polygons).

For some reason (not all the time) when I have then open this table I have my polygons but also the table still contains polylines. What am I doing wrong? I only what a table that contains polygons.

I've added a screenshot below. I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious

[image: lines in polygon]

Answer (score 1):

The normal proces of doing Enclose is like this:

1. Select the polylines you want to "enclose"
2. Make sure your output layer is made editable
3. Pick *Enclose (Polylines to Region)* from the *Create* group on the *SPATIAL* tab

If your editable layer also is the layer you are selecting polylines from, the new polygons will be added to the same layer. This will also mean that you will end up with a layer with polylines as well as polygons.